# Prestashop mail confirmation layout

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a Prestashop 1.7 e-commerce and I'm stuck with a layout problem about the order confirmation that the customer receives. The mail itself works, but it's showed badly when viewed with a smartphone and this because is made using tables with pre-assigned column sizes that I cannot change

[image: screenshot here]

Is there a way to change this layout easily through the Back Office or should I dig into the code?

Answer (score 0):

**Translation tool in the backend**

Log into your PrestaShop admin panel.

Navigate to Localization -> **Translations**, find **Modify translations** section.

Select the **E-mail template translations** from the **Type of translation** dropdown menu, **Core (no theme selected)** and the required language:

[image]

Click **Modify button**.

Open **Core e-mails** and by using search tool (CTRL + F) find order_conf.

You can change the body of the message in WYSIWYG editor, that appears after clicking on
Edit HTML version. And also you can view/edit the .txt version:

[image]

Edit account email in the same way :

[image]

After all changes click **Save** or **Save and stay** button.

Comment: Close enough, but this doesn't help me I'm afraid. In the "modify html" only the dashed line are modifiable while the others, where the variable {products} is, aren't. That variable pastes some html code that contains all the references about the item and the sizes of the column that are creating this issue. Thanks anyway!